# Text in second paragraph gets behind css-shape (after), only in Safari

Tags: html, css, sass

I am making a website and made a shape as a background with an after. Before the background i want some text. I made 2 divs, and within those divs i made two paragraphs. I set the paragraphs to display flex, and to justify space around so they are seperated in 2 blocks in one row. What happens: in Chrome and Firefox everything is oke. In Safari, the last paragraph just disappears. Trying to set z-index doesn't work, or i am doing something wrong. 
Can you help me?
Thanks!

I also made a codepen for this: https://codepen.io/Dehv27/pen/OKmByy

Thanks in advance for the help!

HTML

```
    <section class="intro">
            <div class="text textblok1">
                <p>Test</p>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text textblok2">
                <p>Test</p>
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
        </section>
```

CSS / SCSS:

```
    section.intro{
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 3rem;
        height: 620px;
        &:after{
            content: '';
            position:absolute;
            height: 300px;
            overflow: hidden;
            top: 0;
            right:0;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            z-index: -1;
            background: #3fb9bc;
            transform: perspective(1366px) rotateY(-12deg) scale(1.6);
            border-top: 2px solid black;
            border-bottom: 2px solid black;
        }
        .text{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            p{
                width: 45%;
                span{
                    text-decoration: underline;
                }
            }
        }
        .textblok1{
            padding-top: 6rem;
            transform: rotate(-2deg);
        }
        .textblok2{
            padding-top: 8rem;
            transform: rotate(2.2deg);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something wrong with rotate and scale. If I remove perspective and change rotateY to simple rotate, it will work without any issues ([here is my codepen example](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/41e941e2c8c412b867075c6cf9abf067)):

```
section.intro{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    height: 620px;
    &:after{
        content: '';
        position:absolute;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        top: 0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        z-index: -1;
        background: #3fb9bc;
        transform: rotate(5deg) scale(1.8); //this line is changed and result is the same but no errors in Safari now!
        border-top: 2px solid black;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
```

Comment: Thank so much! That works. Unfortunately then i miss the perspective, which was necessary for the design. Think this is a bug in Safari. But thanks anyway, because now i found the problem.

Comment: @Dehv27 could you please mark the answer as a correct one if it's helpful? =)

Comment: Yes :) Did that!

Comment: @Dehv27 also I've modified my codepen example, so now it uses perspective for 3D and without any Safari issues =)

Comment: Wow this is awesome. Totally works! Can you explain a little bit what happened with the transform-style 3d and the translateZ's in the tekstblok1 and 2 parts? So i can learn from it. Thanks again!!

Comment: @Dehv27 here is a nice article about transform-style - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style, and here - about translateZ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ (in 3d transfroms there are issues with z-indexes and we can use translateZ instead), also recommend you this nice guide about css 3d - https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/

Comment: Thanks again. Will check this out :) Have a nice one.